# Why do we need theorems like the Parallel Axis Theorem?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

In rigid body pure rotation, quantities like $\omega, \tau, L, I, r_i$ (symbol with usual meaning) are axis dependent. Assume rigid body to be sphere rotating about the axis passing trough the center. Now we have the dynamical equation of $\tau = \frac{dL}{dT}$ which would give us the solutions. If we have axis pass through the tangent to sphere, then we have another equation and in unfortunate cases like this we have theorems like [**Parallel Axis Theorem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem) to adjust to the new type of motion. (Note all we are doing is to solve the motion as it is happening). Now my question is since $\omega, \tau, L, I, r_i$ are axis dependent, I don't need to know what axis the the body rotating on, I simply choose my favorite axis and find out the corresponding $\omega, \tau, L, I, r_i$ and solve it? Is this a right way to think about?

P.S One reason I could think off is having a natural way to calculate $\omega$ in the actual rotating axis and no possibility (or complicated) of finding it for another rotation axis than say like finding $I$ and hence the use of **PAT**.

Comment: Why would it need more justification than *"because applying the theorem is often easier than going back to the underlying definition"*? Heck even *"occasionally easier"* would be enough.

Comment: @dmckee I need a confirmation that doing what I have written in question is theoretically valid and the reason I have stated is precisely what it is or has some deeper reasoning?

Comment: Like any other mathematical theorem it has a basic structure of *if [preconditions] then [consequences]*. To know if you can apply it to a particular situation you check that the *[preconditions]* are met. Any proof of the theorem will include the preconditions as will many but not all casual definitions. The Wikipedia page you linked to lists the preconditions in the first paragraph.

Comment: *Why do we need theorems like the Parallel Axis Theorem?*

The answer is that the alternative, going all the down to first principles, is a royal pain, is rather time-consuming, and is subject to errors.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a non homogeneous rigid body. It is rotating about a axis, you have to find say Moment of inertiaabout the axis. So in that case you consider a axis for which it's easy to calculate, and which is parallel to the axis you have to find. For examples, for the axes having origin at the centre of mass, then you can find the M.I easily, then use that theorem to calculate for the required axis.

Answer (score 1):

Basically because you usually calculate them for a particular set of axes. Then it's alright.

The axes you choose are usually the "natural ones", about which the body is symmetrical.

However, you sometimes come up with "Hmmm, now I want to know how these would be if the body rotated about these other axes".

So, instead of re-calculating them again, you just transform your original results with the theorem, and you've finished.

Take into account that calculating moments of inertia use to require triple integrals (one per term, so you can have up to 6 integrals), and they are not always easy (in fact they are rarely easy).

So it's much faster, easier and more comfortable to calculate the easy ones and then transform the tensors.